# jquery contains help

Tags: jquery, contains

I have some html which I would like to manipulate. Its structure is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <nobr>TEXT_TO_LOOK_FOR</nobr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've written a function here which hides the row containing this text, but I'm just wondering if anyone can clean it up. I feel like it is probably making jquery do more work than it needs to.

I know I could search for a row which contains the text, but I want the function to be robust, so that it does not hide rows if the text is found elsewhere.

```
function hideRowContainingText(strText)
{
    var rowMatches = $('tbody tr td nobr:contains(' + '"' + strText + '"' + ')');
    rowMatches.eq(0).parent().parent().parent().css("display", "none");
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: i am new to jQuery, just courious  what is the `(' + '"' + strText + '"' + ')')` what are they needed for?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is equivalent:

```
function hideRowContainingText( strText )
{
    $('td nobr:contains("' + strText + '")').eq(0).closest('tr').hide();
}
```